# Copy contents from docx with bullets intact with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I am trying to copy contents from a docx file to the clipboard eventually. The code I have come up with so far is:

```
package config;

public class buffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlException {
        XWPFDocument srcDoc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("D:\\rules.docx"));

        XWPFDocument destDoc = new XWPFDocument();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.docx");

        for (IBodyElement bodyElement : srcDoc.getBodyElements()) {
            XWPFParagraph srcPr = (XWPFParagraph) bodyElement;
            XWPFParagraph dstPr = destDoc.createParagraph();
            dstPr.createRun();
            int pos = destDoc.getParagraphs().size() - 1;
            destDoc.setParagraph(srcPr, pos);
        }

        destDoc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

This does fetch the bullets but numbers them. I want to retain the original bullet format. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle the numbering definition (in the numbering part) correctly.

The most reliable thing to do would be to copy the definition (both the instance list and the abstract one) across, and renumber it (ie give it a new ID) so that it is unique.

Then of course you'll need to update the ID's in your paragraph to match.

Note that the above is a solution only for the question you have asked.

You'll run into problems if your content contains a rel to some other part (eg an image).  And you'tr not handling the style definition etc.